# Retain form fields after validation fail, "render" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm new to Rails and am trying to modify an app that was written by another team. I have a common problem of needing to retain form fields after a failed validation. In our app, the user submits basic info like name, email, and an invitation code. I validate the invitation code in the controller. If it fails, it currently does a `redirect_to :back` but that loses the info that the user filled in and clears the form. From other pages that I've researched, it seems the proper thing to do is a `render :action => :new`. However, when I try that I get errors.

This attempt...

```
format.html { render :action => "new" }
```

all give the same result of...

> Template is missing
>
> Missing template after_step/new, application/new with...

The way the previous developers set it up, Step 1 of the form is at "users/registrations/new", but the following steps are at "after_step/step_two", etc. So, upon form submission, it is going to "after_step_controller.rb" where I am doing my validation. Obviously, I see that it is trying to render the "new" action on that controller instead of the "registrations_controller.rb".

However, when I try to force it with...

```
format.html { render :template => "registrations_controller/new" }        
format.html { render :action => "new", :controller => "registrations" }
```

...I still get the missing template error. Therefore, I tried other things I found suggested online...

```
format.html { render :template => "users/registrations/new" }
format.html { render :file => "users/registrations/new.html.erb" }
```

These didn't work either as they gave this error:

> undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

I then researched this and most said that the "new" function wasn't creating the new user. However, the code is there so I'm not sure what is going on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this? It's obviously not a show-stopper, but for a better user experience I'd like the form fields to retain their values upon failed validation.

Here's some info...

**users/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => step_two_path) do |f| %>
        <div class="signup_step_mid_content">
          <div class="step_content_block">
            <h3> First, tell us a little bit about yourself:</h3>
            <div class="signup_filed_small mrgn_r_20">
              <label>First Name</label>
              <%= f.text_field :first_name, :title => "First Name", :placeholder => "First Name" %>
            </div>
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    @invite_code = params[:invite_code]
end
```

**after_step_controller.rb**

```
def step_two
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    respond_to do |format|

      @tester = Prefinery::Tester.new(:beta_id => 1234) 
      @tester.email = params[:user][:email]
      @tester.invitation_code = params[:user][:invitation_code]
      @tester.status = 'active' 

      if !@tester.save 
        #format.html{redirect_to :back }

        #format.html { render :template => "registrations_controller/new" }        
        #format.html { render :action => "new", :controller => "registrations" }
        #format.html { render :action => "new" }

        #format.html { render :template => "users/registrations/new" }
        #format.html { render :file => "users/registrations/new.html.erb" }
```

Let me know if any further info is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about this step:

```
format.html { render :template => "users/registrations/new" }
```

The problem is that you're not setting an instance for @user in the "after_step_controller", if you want to do the render, you should have to set an instance for @user, and it should contains the attributes that were submitted in the form, so you could show validations errors.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Boom! I had `@user = User.new(params[:user])` already in the `step_two`, but it was after the render. I needed to create the User instance before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hm. A couple of suggestions here:

```
format.html { render :template => "users/registrations/new" }
```

or just

```
format.html { render "users/registrations/new" }
```

seems the way to go. I would consider cleaning things up though and moving everything in one specific controller for the process though.

- you need to initialize the @user instance variable like so

  @user = User.new(params[:user])

(probably) such that the user in the next form retains the params send by the form.

Comment: You are correct. The variable initialization was in there, but it was **after** the render. I moved it before and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
render :new
```

will do the job for you

Answer (score 1):

I think, you get the

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

exception, because the `new` template uses the variable `@user` but the `step_two` method doesn't define it.

Comment: See edited code. It actually *does* include that, but I hadn't included it in the code above because I didn't think it was pertinent. Is that how it should be? If so, then there's something else because it is there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got it via another comment. I had to move the initialization above the render.

Answer (score 0):

I found that text boxes and radio buttons were being retained, as expected, after a failed model validation.  However, select boxes were having trouble, until I inserted the selected: clause, as in

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <legend>Area of Expertise</legend>
    <%= form.select :srvy_area_of_expertise,
       options_for_select(ThemConstants::AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE,
          **selected: @survey.srvy_area_of_expertise**),
      id: :survey_srvy_area_of_expertise,
      include_blank: true,
      prompt: "Choose one",
      class: "form-control"%>
    <%= text_field_tag :other_area_of_expertise, @survey.srvy_area_of_expertise, class: 'form-control',
      placeholder: "If 'Other' type area of expertise here" %>_
  </div>
```